# Facebook Likes Button Reset to Zero after Website Migration

Tags: facebook, migration, facebook-comments

A client's website has been recently migrated onto a brand new server, and upon migration was completed, all FB button likes and comments simply reset to zero.

Considering that some pages had up to some 10K 'likes' and plenty of comments, it is somehow of a problematic situation now to find out they're all gone. I thought FB would easily associate and store permalink URL to each button, or has this got to do with DNS and/or IP changes?

Website is at: www.insignia-lb.com

Anyone has an idea as per how we can retrieve and get them back? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are sure that nothing has changed (domain, opengraph tags)? All the like buttons have an absolute url in their href parameter?

Comment: also maybe can you post the code of on of the resetted like button